# How can I overwrite an existing array item when pushing new data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have list of items. When clicking on an item, I push it to an array.
The thing is, I want to make it so that when I click on a new item, it will get pushed AND overwrite the previous item that I pushed.

There should always only be ONE item in the array.

Currently the click method that I use look like this

```
  selectedSourceCar: {
    get() {
      return this.cars && this.cars.find(car => car.selectedSource);
    },
    set(newValue) {
      newValue.selectedDestination = false;
      this.cars.forEach(car => car.selectedSource = car === newValue);
      this.fields = null;
      Promise
        .all([
          axios.getFields(getType(newValue.carType)).then(result => {
            this.fields = Object.entries(result.data).map(([name, type]) => ({name, type, selected: false}))}),
          unitService.getFullUnitInformationForCopyUnitFunctionality(newValue.id).then(result => {
            this.fullSelectedCar.push({
              fullCarNumber: `${this.properties.find(owner => owner.id === result.data.ownerId).ownerNumber}-${result.data.carNumber}`,
              selectedSource: false,
              selectedDestination: false,
              ...result.data
            });
          }),
        ])
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
  },
```

As it is now, if I click car1, car2, car3, then they will all be saved in the fullSelectedCar array, but what I want it to do is: if I click car1, it will be pushed to the array. Then if I click car2, then it will replace car1 in the array, and so on.

Comment: I believe you need to create a copy of the previously added data, so you create a reference of what's going to be replaced when something is pushed again.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just assign a new array? I.e.

```
this.fullSelectedCar = [{
  ...result.data
  ...
}];
```

Alternatively, you can just clear the array before you push, a simple way in JS is to set length to 0:

```
this.fullSelectedCar.length = 0
this.fullSelectedCar.push({...});
```

Seems simple enough. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Hey, Vue does not reactive when updated to the array's length directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check, if no data is present in the array, then push the clicked else override the first object always.

**Important-** Use `$set` to make modifications in the array so it would be reactive.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fullSelectedCar: [],
      cars: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Volvo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Toyota"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Honda"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pushToArr(payload) {
      // If no data is present in the array
      if(!this.fullSelectedCar.length) {
        this.fullSelectedCar.push(payload)
        return;
      } 
      // override the first index data every time
      this.$set(this.fullSelectedCar, 0, payload);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  fullSelectedCar - {{ fullSelectedCar }}<br><br>
  <b>Click on any car</b>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="car in cars" @click="pushToArr(car)">{{ car.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```